# Toggling values for Preferred Band for Wi-Fi card on Windows - can I automate it using Powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Due to a group policy applied to my work laptop, I need to toggle the following setting every time when I reboot the laptop to use Second Screen, an app that enables pen and touch input from a Samsung tablet.

Is there a good way, say, via PowerShell, to quickly toggle this option?

Many thanks!

[image]

---

**What brought me here:**
Effectively, over Second Screen, the Samsung tablet will be added a wireless display to the work laptop. For now, it takes a good number of mouse-clicks to get to toggle the Preferred Band value. Now, it has now become a real chore when I cannot avoid rebooting the laptop two times a day. (Long story short, I also use eGPU with the work laptop, which creates frequent annoyance as keyboard+mouse lag. The only solution to this input issue is to reboot the laptop. What triggers such lags is yet unclear.)

---

Reference: I took the screenshot from [this page](https://wccftech.com/how-to/how-to-change-between-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wifi-bands-on-windows-10/), which also gave a step-by-step walkthrough for getting to such setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell, you can get a list of all the advanced properties by running:

`Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "*"`

This will return all the settings that you are able to see in the above list.

But first, we need to get the name of the adapter we want to change the value for. Run `Get-NetAdapter` to see what the name of your wi-fi adapter is.

Next, you can set the value of the preferred band by the following:

`Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Preferred Band" -DisplayValue "3. Prefer 5GHz band"`

where "Wi-Fi" is the name of the wireless adapter.

**Note:**This must be run from an administrative powershell instance.

`

Comment: Adding to '@Nazzard' helpful answer,  You can dynamically get your adapter list this way.  ```Get-NetAdapter | ForEach-Object {$PSitem | Select-Object -Property Name, InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, Status, MacAddress,  LinkSpeed, @{Name = 'IPAddress'; Expression = {(Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex ($PSItem).ifindex).IPv4Address}}}```, if you are doing this across multiple target systems.  Most settings like this are Group/Local policy settings in the registry. So, one could use GPO/LPO to set that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running the following three lines through an alias. On my work laptop, only the third option would work.

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Preferred Band" -DisplayValue "3. Prefer 5GHz band"
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Preferred Band" -DisplayValue "1. No Preference"
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Preferred Band" -DisplayValue "3. Prefer 5GHz band"
```

Then, I added the following alias in `c:\users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, where the script above was named as `switch_wifi.ps1`.

```
function Do-whichwifi {
    Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Preferred Band"
}

function Do-switchWiFi {
    c:\Users\lilinfen\path_to\ps1_file\switch_wifi.ps1
}

Set-Alias whichWiFi Do-whichwifi 
Set-Alias switchWiFi Do-switchWiFi
```

---

Then, for day-to-day usage, when I need to use the Second Screen app, I'll start a PowerShell console as admin and issue the alias `switchWiFi`.